# Snap SVG animation - Infinite Loop Freezing

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, infinite-loop, snap.svg

I have issues trying to loop [this animation](https://jsfiddle.net/_avisseau/3sqpe1d9/):

```
svg = document.getElementById("shape");
s = Snap(svg);

var l2 = Snap.select('#line2');


animatePath(); 

function animatePath(){

    l2.animate({ d: "M328.2,29.9c-51.6,8.3-65.9-2.5-79.4,23.5c-5.4,10.5-12.8,24.3-21.6,47.7c-14.7,38.6-131.1,9.1-37.8,108.8c92.8,99.6,101.9,43.3,89.2,22.9c-7.1-11.4,40.5-1.6,95.5-3.7c18.3-0.6,37.1-2.8,54.8-7.5c71.7-19.1,12-85.7-47-119.9S398.5,18.6,328.2,29.9z" }, 1000, mina.ease, resetPath);

}



function resetPath(){

    l2.animate({ d: "M218.5,85.1c-8,18.9-33.1,25.7-43.6,40.9c-10.8,15.6-9.5,38,38.5,89.3c93.2,99.6,121,58.2,107.9,37.8c-9.8-15.3-7.6-35.7,64.8-53.5c49.3-12,56.4-24.5,36.9-42c-9.5-8.5-24.7-18.3-43.8-29.8c-10.8-6.5-17-13.5-20.3-20.6c-14.5-30.5,25.4-61.6-32.3-51.8C256.6,67.4,252.6,4.4,218.5,85.1z" }, 1000, mina.ease, animatePath);


}
```

The first loop is fine, but a few seconds later animation starts to freeze.

I guess the problem comes from the callback but after many tries I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work fine for single animations, but gets messed up for multiple ones ?

I think the problem is that you have lots of the same callbacks firing at the same time, so you end up in an escalating loop.

Just have one callback in each function from one of the animations, rather than one for every animation. So you only call resetPath or animatePath after one animation, and remove the callbacks off the other animations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes, it was working perfect with a single animation.

I removed multiple callbacks in each functions, worked just fine. 
Thanks a lot for your assistance.